# No certificate found

Tags: c#, azure

I'm trying to authenticate a user for the Azure management API. I'm following this tutorial for that:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460782.aspx

However, when I execute it, I always get a "certificate not found" error. What could cause this? My code is exactly the same as in the example:

```
        // Values for the subscription ID and List Hosted Services operation.
        // 
        string subscriptionId = "****************";

        // The opperation to be performed. This value can be modified to reflect the operation being performed.
        string operationName = "hostedservices";

        // Build a URI for https://management.core.windows.net/<subscription-id>/services/<operation-type>
        Uri requestUri = new Uri("https://management.core.windows.net/"
                                + subscriptionId
                                + "/services/"
                                + operationName);

        // Create the request and specify attributes of the request.
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(requestUri);

        // Define the requred headers to specify the API version and operation type.
        request.Headers.Add("x-ms-version", "2010-10-28");
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.ContentType = "application/xml";


        // The thumbprint value of the management certificate.
        // You must replace the string with the thumbprint of a 
        // management certificate associated with your subscription.
        string certThumbprint = "*************";

        // Create a reference to the My certificate store.
        X509Store certStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);

        // Try to open the store.
        try
        {
            certStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            if (e is CryptographicException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: The store is unreadable.");
            }
            else if (e is SecurityException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: You don't have the required permission.");
            }
            else if (e is ArgumentException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: Invalid values in the store.");
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        // Find the certificate that matches the thumbprint.
        X509Certificate2Collection certCollection = certStore.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, certThumbprint, false);
        certStore.Close();

        // Check to see if our certificate was added to the collection. If no, throw an error, if yes, create a certificate using it.
        if (0 == certCollection.Count)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error: No certificate found containing thumbprint " + certThumbprint);
        }

        // Create an X509Certificate2 object using our matching certificate.
        X509Certificate2 certificate = certCollection[0];

        // Attach the certificate to the request.
        request.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);

        try
        {
            // Make the call using the web request.
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            // Display the web response status code.
            Console.WriteLine("Response status code: " + response.StatusCode);

            // Display the request ID returned by Windows Azure.
            if (null != response.Headers)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("x-ms-request-id: "
                + response.Headers["x-ms-request-id"]);
                Console.ReadKey();
            }

            // Parse the web response.
            Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);

            // Display the raw response.
            Console.WriteLine("Response output:");
            Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
            Console.ReadKey();

            // Close the resources no longer needed.
            response.Close();
            responseStream.Close();
            reader.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }

    }
```

Comment: You should add detail of what you are doing to this very question. Forcing others to visit an out-link just to pick up the gist of your question is bad etiquette (IMO).

Comment: Okay, sorry for that. I'll edit the post.

Comment: Can you check if the certificate by that thumbprint is there in your certificate store?

Comment: and to amplify Gaurav's comment - the cert MUST be in CurrentUser store according to your code.